# vfp.h in the accelerate framework doesn't link on XCode 4.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks, accelerate-framework

I'm using the Accelerate framework to boost the performance of a piece of code that I'm running on iPhone. 
I require two headers from Accelerate which are vdsp and vfp. vDSP works perfectly, however I'm getting "use of undeclared identifier" when I use a function from vfp.

Here's the weird thing:
When I run on the simulator, my code runs nicely (even though the editor still points to an error), and the results I expect from the functions used in vfp are there. 
But when I try to run on a device, I get the error.

Which means that I have my files linked correctly. Since the function works, but XCode is confused since it still says undeclared function. Or is it that iOS do not support vfp? Even though with the vector processor they should. 
Help please :)

Comment: You may want to remove the "vfp" tag from this question. On StackOverflow, the "vfp" tag refers to "Visual FoxPro"; you can see that if you hover your mouse over the tag.

Comment: Removed the "vfp" tag, per Tamar's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `vfp.h` header:

```
extern vFloat vceilf( vFloat A ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_NA);
```

`__IPHONE_NA` means "not available on iOS".  The Accelerate framework on iOS 4.x consists only of the vDSP, LAPACK and BLAS libraries.  Please file a bug to request the features that would be useful to you!

Comment: Without breaking NDA, they may also wish to read the API diffs on iOS 5.0: http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html .